# I get an error when I want to select in constructor in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I get an error in my ASP.NET Core Web API project when want to select all content:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext

This is my `contentService`:

```
    private IContentRepository contentRepository;
    private DbContext_CMS dbContext;
   
    public ContentService(IContentRepository contentRepository, DbContext_CMS dbContext )
    {
        this.contentRepository = contentRepository;
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ContentInfoDTO>  GetAllContent()
    {
        try
        {
            IQueryable<Content> contents = contentRepository.GetAll();

            IEnumerable<ContentInfoDTO> result = contents.Select(content => new ContentInfoDTO(content)).ToList();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is `ContentInfoDTO.cs`:

```
public class ContentInfoDTO
{
    public ContentInfoDTO(Content content)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Id = content.Id;
            this.Title = content.Title;
            this.Description = content.Description;
          
            this.BodyHtml = content.BodyHtml;
            this.ContentCategories = content.ContentCategories.Select(category => new CategoryInfoDTO(category.FkCmsCategory)).ToList(); //this line error
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }       
    public string? BodyHtml { get; set; }
  
    public ICollection<CategoryInfoDTO>? ContentCategories { get; set; }
}
```

This is my `CategoryInfoDTO`:

```
public class CategoryInfoDTO
{
    public CategoryInfoDTO(Category? category)
    {
        if (category != null)
        {
            this.Id = category.Id;
            this.Title = category.Title;
            this.Description = category.Description;
            this.FkParentId = category.FkParentId;
        }
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public int? FkParentId { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my `dbContext` configured:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                      .UseLazyLoadingProxies()                        
                      .UseSqlServer("connectionString");
        }
}
```

I also fixed dependency injection, but it didn't work.

```
service.AddDbContext<DbContext_CMS>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `contentService`:

```
IEnumerable<ContentInfoDTO> result = contents.Select(content => new ContentInfoDTO(content)).ToList();
```

in the `Select` method you start by getting `Content` entities from the database. At the moment you start getting your first `Content`, the `DbContext` instance provided to you by Dependency Injection is in use.

Next, while still inside the `Select` method, you take the `Content` entity, create a new `ContentInfoDTO` object and pass the entity into the constructor. In the constructor of `ContentInfoDTO`, specifically at the line you get your error,

```
this.ContentCategories = content.ContentCategories.Select(category => new CategoryInfoDTO(category.FkCmsCategory)).ToList();
```

you access the `ContentCategories` property, which is a navigation property belonging to `Content`. Since the `Content` entity you passed into the constructor was provided by EF Core, it is being tracked by EF Core, which means when you tried to perform an operation on `ContentCategories` property, EF Core tried to perform a [lazy loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy) of all the `Category` entities related to that `Content` instance. However, since we're still inside the first `Select` method and the `DbContext` instance is still in use there, we tried to access the same `DbContext` from different places at the same time, hence the error.

You could force the retrieval of the `ContentCategories` collection earlier using the `Include` method and see if that solves the problem - see [eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager).

Also, I don't think you need to inject your DbContext in `contentService`, since you seem to use the repository pattern and retrieve your entities from there, I assume the DbContext is already injected into your repository instance.

**Edit** : it should be lazy loading instead of explicit loading. Also that's assuming that the lazy loading related package is installed and configuration has been done and that the navigation property is virtual. If your situation doesn't cover any of the requirements, your error may be from something else